# Remove keys which have empty arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I need to delete sub keys which have empty arrays:

```
  networks = {
    "CL1": {
      "192.168.200.0/24": [

      ],
      "192.168.56.0/24": [
        "192.168.56.57",
        "192.168.56.84",
      ]
    },
    "CL2": {
      "192.168.222.0/24": [
        "192.168.222.224",
      ]
    }
  }
```

to

```
  networks = {
    "CL1": {
      "192.168.56.0/24": [
        "192.168.56.57",
        "192.168.56.84",
      ]
    },
    "CL2": {
      "192.168.222.0/24": [
        "192.168.222.224",
      ]
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to remove key elements which have empty array?

Answer (score 2):

```
networks.transform_values { |v| v.reject { |_,a| a.empty? } }
  #=> {:CL1=>{:"192.168.56.0/24"=>["192.168.56.57", "192.168.56.84"]},
  #    :CL2=>{:"192.168.222.0/24"=>["192.168.222.224"]}}
```

See [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) and [Hash#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-reject). The former made its debut in MRI v2.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new one by filtering empty keys in the inner hash.

```
networks = networks.map {|key, inner_hash|  [key, inner_hash.select{|k, v| v.any?}.to_h]}
                   .to_h
puts networks
# {
#     :CL1 => {
#         :"192.168.56.0/24" => ["192.168.56.57", "192.168.56.84"]
#     }, 
#     :CL2 => {
#         :"192.168.222.0/24" => ["192.168.222.224"]
#     }
# }
```